# To Display 8 images and texts in single activity using ArraryAdapter

Tags: android, listview

Here I have 17 images and I want to display these in activity (2 images in a row) using `Grid Layout` but on `getview()` call method.

How can I set limit of the number of images in a single activity.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowData rowData=null;
    rowData = getItem(TabbedHorizontalPagerDemo.startWith);

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    ImageView imageView1 = holder.getImage();
    imageView1.setImageResource(rowData.mImgid);

    TextView textView1 = holder.getTextView();
    textView1.setText(rowData.mTitle);
    TabbedHorizontalPagerDemo.startWith++;
    return convertView;
}

/*
 * Class to get values from a single row of list view
 */
private class ViewHolder
{
    private View mRow;
    private TextView textView = null;
    private ImageView image = null;

    public ViewHolder(View row){
        mRow = row;
    }

    public ImageView getImage(){
        if(image == null)
            image = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        return image;
    }

    public TextView getTextView(){
        if(textView == null)
            textView = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.imgText);
        return textView;
    }       
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question, I think you need to sort your `RowData (TabbedHorizontalPagerDemo.startWith)` in the order you need to display before using it in the GridView.

Comment: is your R.layout.list have two imageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as by return 8 in `getCount()` method. So its giving the 8 images on single activity.

```
public int getCount() {
    return 8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in *getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent)* of your programming code.Here I have taken data from database. May be it will solve your Problem:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridstyle, null);
this.c.moveToPosition(pos);      
String albumName = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("albumname"));
String image = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("image_data"));
ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagestyle);
    if (image != null) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(image);
        iv.setImageURI(uri);
            }

TextView fname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textstyle);
fname.setText(albumName);
```